# Print only correct path of a maze

Tags: python, python-3.x

ı have some codes for solve a maze recursively. In a list of lists, "x" represents path, "w" represents wall and "+" represents visited cell. I only want to write correct path but my function writes every path even it is a dead end. Can you please tell me what am I missing here?Below you can see my some of codes:

```
    mainMaze = [['W', 'W', 'P', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
                ['W', 'W', 'P', 'W', 'P', 'S'],
                ['W', 'W', 'P', 'W', 'P', 'W'],
                ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'W'],
                ['F', 'W', 'P', 'W', 'W', 'W'],
                ['W', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'W']]


    def printMaze(maze):
        for line in maze:
            for element in line:
                print(element, end=" ")
            print()


    def pathCheck(row, col):
        print(str(row) + "," + str(col))
        if mainMaze[row][col] == "F":  # F is exit
            mainMaze[i][j] == "0"
            return True
        elif mainMaze[row][col] == "W":  # W is wall
            return False
        elif mainMaze[row][col] == "+":  # + is visited
            return False
        elif mainMaze[row][col] == "P":  # + is visited
            mainMaze[row][col] = "+"
        mainMaze[i][j] == "0"
        if ((row < len(mainMaze) - 1 and pathCheck(row + 1, col))
                or (col > 0 and pathCheck(row, col - 1))
                or (row > 0 and pathCheck(row - 1, col))
                or (col < len(mainMaze) - 1 and pathCheck(row, col + 1))):
            return True

        return False


    for i in range(len(mainMaze)):
        for j in range(len(mainMaze)):
            if mainMaze[i][j] == "S":
                a, k = i, j
    pathCheck(a, k)
    printMaze(mainMaze)
```

Comment: Could you post the print function as well? Also, the forth statement in the last check is not correct

Comment: print function added. Can you please explain why it is wrong, sir?

Comment: You should provide a working example to get the help you need: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you will get a more accurate answer and probably faster if you provide a fully working example.

Anyway, I made couple of guesses and I hope it is your use case.

If you add `print(str(row) + "," + str(col))` at the beginning of `pathCheck`, you will see what is wrong.

Now consider this:

```
mainMaze = [
    ["X", "X", "A"],
    ["W", "X", "X"],
    ["W", "X", "G"]
]
def pathCheck(row, col):
    print(str(row) + "," + str(col))
    if mainMaze[row][col] == "G":  # F is exit
        return True
    elif mainMaze[row][col] == "W":  # W is wall
        return False
    elif mainMaze[row][col] == "+":  # + is visited
        return False
    elif mainMaze[row][col] == "X":  # X is path
        mainMaze[row][col] = "+"

    if ((row < len(mainMaze) - 1 and pathCheck(row + 1, col))
            or (col > 0 and pathCheck(row, col - 1))
            or (row > 0 and pathCheck(row - 1, col))
            or (col < len(mainMaze) - 1 and pathCheck(row, col - 1))
            or (col < len(mainMaze) - 1 and pathCheck(row, col + 1))):
        return True
    return False
```

it will print:

```
0,0
1,0
0,-1 // wrong
0,1
1,1
2,1
2,0
1,1
2,0
2,2
```

The negative index will turn and in this case gets converted to (0,2). It will produce unwanted results.

The reason is `col < len(mainMaze) - 1 and pathCheck(row, col - 1)` where if `col` is 0 then the first condition is met and then it will get to (row, -1).

If this is not a problem in your code (which definitely is a coding issue and potential bug) then you need to post a full example including the matrix.

Comment: Post the example that you mentioned in your question. There should be an example that you found out your code is printing all the paths